# Reading Adobe .issue file in objective C / Epub

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, adobe, epub

Hi folks,                                                                                         am developing a ipad application which should read a Adobs's .issue file and display.

Here i dont have any .issue file use and create sample. Where to get that file ?. If there is any link to download .issue file will be helpful.

And also how to read a .issue file in objective c.?

There is a app in app-store named wired app which reads .issue and displays. i dont know how that people developed that application and also there is no examples out there in net for reading .issue file.

Any idea and suggestions will be helpful.

Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Unless you're prepared to reverse-engineer the format yourself you're out of luck.

The `.issue` file format is a propriety format belonging to Adobe for use with their Digital Content Viewer, which can be licensed and branded. This is what Wired use to produce their digital magazine.

> This new .issue format is a compressed file format that contains vertical and horizontal magazine layouts, metadata, code to enable interactivity, and associated assets (images, video, etc.) Once the layouts have been packaged into the .issue format, the file is then rendered and displayed to the end-user using a publisher-branded Digital Content Viewer. **The WIRED Reader, for example, is the first instance of a publisher-branded viewer**. This Digital Content Viewer allows readers to interact with and navigate through the magazine content (including via the innovative “browse” mode). Previously we announced the Digital Content Viewer for Apple iPad; in the future we also expect to develop the Digital Content Viewer on Adobe AIR for desktops and other devices.

You can find out more about Adobe's digital publishing platform [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitalpublishingsuite/)

Comment: Is there a possibility to crreate an app through which the .issue files can be uncompressed and can be read? Or should i use only adobe's digital content viewer to read .issue files?

Comment: There a possibility to do anything you want, but it'll be an awful lot of work as you'll need to reverse engineer the file manually as it's a closed format so no file specification docs exist. Why are you specifically interested in the .issue format? Can you not use .mobi or .ePub which are open formats?

Comment: if am using .epub or .mobi in the sense my entire content layout will be get spoiled.. this is the only reason am preferring .issue file formate. Now i created a .issue file using adobe indesign but i dnt know hw to uncompress and use it in objective C.

Comment: Why would your content layout get spoiled? Take a look at the [Baker Framework](http://bakerframework.com/) and the [PugPig Framework](http://pugpig.com/) to see what you can do on the iOS platform with those respective formats.

Comment: Got it micpringle thanks for your suggestion and idea. its really helpful for me to build steps in my app..